# Facebook APP to create posts for fanpage stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im using a script, hosted on my server to create sheduled posts for a few facebook fanpages. Im the admin of the app but not the creator. The guys who created the script does not support the script anymore...

**EDIT:** By stopped working i mean - the process of the upload in the backend of the script runs as always, but the sheduled posts are not generated in facebook. Nothing there... Normally all the images should listed in my planned posts section of the fanpage. I cant find the error. The app is also not blocked.

The current app **(facebook 2.0 API)** uses submission for manage_pages and publish_pages. When i access the app and try to upload images, the fb entry dialog to the app shows up following Message:

> Submit for Login Review
>   Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.

I submited a review for the app and get following answers for each submission:

for "publish_pages" & "manage_pages":

> Your app needs permission for their current functionality. You may have to request another authorization or you can public_profile use the property for their use you need a separate authorization.

Notes From Your Reviewer:

> You don’t need any extended permissions for an app that you admin. App admins, and any account listed as a ‘role’ in the App Settings page, can access all permissions without submitting for review. You only need to submit for review if the users/customers of your app are using the permissions to enhance their experience in-app

I already tried a dozen of tutorials, the publish_action submission and so on - no luck or not enough knowledge. Maybe the second one :)

Here is the index.php of the script: (Any help will be greatly appreciated!)

```html
<?php
define('PATH', dirname(__file__));
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged']!=true){
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit(0);
}
require_once(PATH . '/lang.php');
require_once(PATH . '/config.php');
require_once(PATH . '/createDatabase.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
  $db->delete("pages", "ID",  $_GET['id']); 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  window.location = "index.php"
//-->
  </script>';
  exit(0);
}

require_once(PATH . '/header.php');

if (isset($_POST['rss'])) {
  if(strlen($_POST['rss'])>5){
    $db->insert("rss",array('url' => strip_tags($_POST['rss'])));
  }
}

if(!function_exists('curl_init')){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ' . $l['errorcurl'] . '
  </div>';
  exit(0);
}

if(!isset($idApp) || $idApp == ""){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ' . $l['errorappid'] . '
  </div>';
  exit(0);
}

if(!isset($appSecret) || $appSecret == ""){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ' . $l['errorappsecret'] . '
  </div>';
  exit(0);
}

if(!isset($canvasUrl) || $canvasUrl == ""){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ' . $l['errorcanvas'] . '
  </div>';
  exit(0);
}

if(!isset($folder) || $folder == ""){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ' . $l['errorfolder'] . '
  </div>';
  exit(0);
}


if(isset($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"])) {
  $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
  $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
  $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];
  
  $name = explode(".", $filename);
  $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
  foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
    if($mime_type == $type) {
      $okay = true;
      break;
    } 
  }
  
  $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
  if(!$continue) {
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    ' . $l['errorzip'] . '
    </div>';
  }

  $target_path = PATH . "/" . $folder . "/" .$filename;  // change this to the correct site path
  if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true) {
      $zip->extractTo(PATH . "/" . $folder . "/"); // change this to the correct site path
      $zip->close();

      unlink($target_path);
    }
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    ' . $l['successzip'] . '
    </div>';
  } else {  
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    ' . $l['errorupload'] . '
    </div>';
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['deleteFolder'])){

  function rrmdir($dir) {
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
       }
     }
     reset($objects);
     rmdir($dir);
   }
 }

 if(is_dir(PATH . '/' . $_POST['deleteFolder'])){
  rrmdir(PATH . '/' . $_POST['deleteFolder']);
}


}

?>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <hr>
    <div id="tab" class="nav nav-pills pull-right" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <a href="index.php#price2" onclick="window.location='index.php'" class="btn btn-large btn-info active" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['config'];?></a>
      <a href="#features2" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['pages'];?></a>
      <a href="#requests2" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['posts'];?></a>
      <a href="#folders" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['folders'];?></a>
      <a href="#live" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['liveposts'];?></a>
      <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-large btn-info" onclick="window.location='logout.php'" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $l['logout'];?></a>
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />


    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices2">
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $l['configinfo'];?></div>
        <p class="lead"><?php echo $l['config'];?></p>
        <!--Body content-->
        <legend><?php echo $l['configproblems'];?></legend>

        <?php 
        if (count($db->selectAll("config"))>0) {
         echo '<button class="btn btn-success">' . $l['youhavetoken'] . '</button>';
         echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . $idApp. '&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages&response_type=token&redirect_uri=' . $canvasUrl . '"><button class="btn btn-info">' . $l['renewtoken'] . '</button></a>';

       } else {
         echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . $idApp. '&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages&response_type=token&redirect_uri=' . $canvasUrl . '"><button class="btn btn-info">' . $l['gettoken'] . '</button></a>';
       }

       ?>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="features2">
      <br>
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <?php echo $l['pagesinfo'];?>
      </div>
      <p class="lead"><?php echo $l['pages'];?></p>
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend><?php echo $l['addpages'];?></legend>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="page"><?php echo $l['pageurl'];?></label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input id="page" name="page" type="text" placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/your-page-url" class="input-xlarge" required="">
              <p class="help-block"><?php echo $l['pageurl'];?></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="add"></label>
            <div class="controls">
              <button id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $l['add'];?></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
        $resultToken = $db->selectAll("config");
        if(isset($resultToken[0]['token']))
          $token = $resultToken[0]['token'];
        function getSslPage($url) {
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $result;
        }
        $info = json_decode(getSslPage('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $_POST['page'] . '?access_token=' . $token));
        if(isset( $info->name)){
          $album = json_decode(getSslPage('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $info->id . '/albums?fields=id&access_token=' . $token));
          $fotoAlbum = "";
          foreach ($album->data as $key => $value) {
            if($fotoAlbum=="" || @$album->data[$key]->name == "Timeline Photos"){
              $fotoAlbum = @$album->data[$key]->id;
            }
          }
          $db->insert("pages",array('ID' => $info->id , 'url' => $info->name, 'idalbum' => $fotoAlbum));
          unset($_POST);
        }
      }

      $result = $db->selectAll("pages");
      if(!empty($result)){
       echo '<table class="table table-striped" id="example">
       <thead>
       <tr>
       <td>' . $l['name'] . '</td>
       <td>' . $l['id'] . '</td>
       <td>' . $l['open'] . '</td>
       <td>' . $l['delete'] . '</td>
       </tr> 
       </thead>
       <tbody>';
       foreach ($result as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>' , $value['url'] ,  '</td><td>' , $value['ID'] , '</td><td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/' , $value['ID'] , '">' . $l['open'] . '</a></td><td><a href="?id=' , $value['ID'] , '">' . $l['delete'] . '</a></td></tr>';
      } 
      echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="folders">
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $l['foldersinfo'];?></div>
    <p class="lead"><?php echo $l['folders'];?></p>

    <legend><?php echo $l['uploadzipfolders'];?></legend>
    <?php if(isset($message)) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
      <label><?php echo $l['choosezip'];?>: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $l['upload'];?>" />
    </form>

    <legend><?php echo $l['deletefolder'];?></legend>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <select id="deleteFolder" name="deleteFolder" class="input-xlarge" required>
        <?php 
        $folders = glob(PATH . '/' . $folder . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
        foreach ($folders as $subfolder){
          $subfolder = explode('/', $subfolder);
          echo '<option value="' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] ,  '">' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] , '/' ,  '</option>';
        } 
        ?>
      </select><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $l['deletefolder'];?>" />
    </form>

    <legend><?php echo $l['uploadimagestofolder'];?></legend>
    <select id="puthere" name="puthere" class="input-xlarge" required>
      <?php 
      echo '<option value="' , $folder , '">' , $folder ,  ' (root) </option>';
      $folders = glob(PATH . '/' . $folder . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
      foreach ($folders as $subfolder){
        $subfolder = explode('/', $subfolder);
        echo '<option value="' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] ,  '">' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] , '/' ,  '</option>';
      } 
      ?>
    </select>

    <div id="file-uploader-demo1">    
      <noscript>      
        <p><?php echo $l['enablejavascript'];?></p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
      </noscript>         
    </div>

    <div class="qq-upload-extra-drop-area"><?php echo $l['dropfiles'];?></div>


  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="live">
   <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $l['rssinfo'];?></div>
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    <fieldset>

      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend><?php echo $l['addyourrss'];?></legend>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="page"><?php echo $l['rssurl'];?></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="rss" name="rss" type="text" placeholder="https://www.something.com/rss" class="input-xlarge" required="">
          <p class="help-block"><?php echo $l['rssurl'];?></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="add"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $l['add'];?></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <legend><?php echo $l['startpostlive'];?></legend>
  <?php echo $l['startpostlive'];?>

  <!-- Select Basic -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['pickyourrss'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="urlRss" name="urlRss" class="input-xlarge" multiple required>
        <?php 
        $result = $db->selectAll("rss");
        if(!empty($result)){
         foreach ($result as $value){
          echo '<option value="' , $value['url'] , '">' , $value['url'] ,  '</option>';
        } 
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['pages'];?></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="pageRss" name="pageRss" class="input-xlarge" multiple required>
      <?php 
      $result = $db->selectAll("pages");
      if(!empty($result)){
       foreach ($result as $value){
        echo '<option value="' , $value['ID'] , '">' , $value['url'] ,  '</option>';
      } 
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
</div>


<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['timetocheck'];?></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="timeRss" name="timeRss" class="input-xlarge" required>
      <option value="5">5 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="10">10 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="15">15 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="20">20 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="30">30 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="45">45 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
      <option value="60">60 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="startRss" name="startRss" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $l['startposting'];?></button>
<button id="stopRss" name="stopRss" class="btn btn-info" style="display:none" onClick="window.location.reload()"><?php echo $l['stopposting'];?></button>
<div id="postsDone"></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="requests2">
  <br>
  <p class="lead"><?php echo $l['posts'];?></p>

  <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;" id="formPosts">
    <fieldset>
     <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $l['postsinfo'];?></div>
     <!-- Form Name -->
     <legend><?php echo $l['generateposts'];?></legend>

     <!-- Select Basic -->
     <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['folder'];?></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select id="subfolder" name="subfolder" class="input-xlarge" required>
          <?php 
          echo '<option value="' , $folder , '">' , $folder ,  ' (root) </option>';
          $folders = glob(PATH . '/' . $folder . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
          foreach ($folders as $subfolder){
            $subfolder = explode('/', $subfolder);
            echo '<option value="' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] ,  '">' , $folder , '/', $subfolder[count($subfolder)-1] , '/' ,  '</option>';
          } 
          ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['pages'];?></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select id="page" name="page[]" class="input-xlarge" multiple required>
          <?php 
          $result = $db->selectAll("pages");
          if(!empty($result)){
           foreach ($result as $value){
            echo '<option value="' , $value['ID'] , '">' , $value['url'] ,  '</option>';
          } 
        }
        ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Select Basic -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['usefilename'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="useimagename" name="useimagename" class="input-xlarge" required>
        <?php 
        echo '<option value="0">' , $l['no'] ,  '</option>';
        echo '<option value="1">' , $l['yes'] ,  '</option>';
        ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select Basic -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['deletefiles'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="deletefiles" name="deletefiles" class="input-xlarge" required>
        <?php 
        echo '<option value="0">' , $l['no'] ,  '</option>';
        echo '<option value="1">' , $l['yes'] ,  '</option>';
        ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['numberofposts'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="10" checked="checked">
        10
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="25">
        25
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="50">
        50
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="100">
        100
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="250">
        250
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="numposts" value="500">
        500
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['timefirstpost'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
        <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="dataehora" name="dataehora" required></input>
        <span class="add-on">
          <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
          </i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['timebettweenpost'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="2m">
        2 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="3m">
        3 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="5m" checked="checked">
        5 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="10m">
        10 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="15m">
        15 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="20m">
        20 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="30m">
        30 <?php echo $l['minutes'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="1h">
        1 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="2h">
        2 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="3h">
        3 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="4h">
        4 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="5h">
        5 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="6h">
        6 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="12h">
        12 <?php echo $l['hours'];?>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['maxpostsperday'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="postsperday" name="postsperday"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $l['from'];?></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="from" value="folder" checked="checked">
        <?php echo $l['randomimages'];?>
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="from" value="file">
        <?php echo $l['file'];?>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="generatePosts" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $l['generate'];?></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
</form>

<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>

<div id="defaultText" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" val="" class="text" />
  <select class="input-xlarge" required>
    <?php 
    echo '<option value="0">' , $l['begginingempty'] ,  '</option>';
    echo '<option value="1">' , $l['endempty'] ,  '</option>';
    echo '<option value="2">' , $l['begginingall'] ,  '</option>';
    echo '<option value="3">' , $l['endall'] ,  '</option>';
    ?>
  </select>

  <button name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success addDescription"><?php echo $l['add']; ?></button>
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails" id="listaposts">

</ul>
<br clear="all" />
<div class="alert alert-success sucessoPost" style="display:none">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <?php echo $l['successposts'];?>
</div>


<div class="options" style="display:none">

  <div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <?php echo $l['dontclose'];?>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button id="postall" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $l['postall'];?></button>
  <a onClick="window.location.reload()" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-error"><?php echo $l['deleteall'];?></a>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<?php 
require_once(PATH . '/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking here. As the reviewer told you, you don’t need to get permissions reviewed, if you are only going to use that app yourself – users with a role in tha app can be asked for any permission, without review. So now we’re at the part where you need to tell us, what “stopped working” actually means.

Comment: @CBroe - By stopped working i mean - the precess of the upload in the backend of the script runs as always, but the sheduled posts are not generated in facebook. Nothing there... Normally all the images should listed in my planned posts section of the fanpage. I cant find the error. The app is also not blocked. i updated my question. thx

Comment: Well then there’s probably error messages returned from the API, but your app doesn’t show them – so that would be the first thing to fix. (But I am not going to look through that wagonload of code you just dumped here to find where the right place to do that would be. Either you do that yourself – or hire a developer, if you lack the skillset.)

Comment: Ok i understand - maybe another one can help me. In the mean time i will try to debug and hopefully find the problem. best